# Hadoop fs mkdir and testing using FileSystem.exists

Tags: hadoop

I can create directories in my hadoop using: hadoop fs -mkdir /test/input. I can check this by browsing localhost:50070 and it works:

```
/test
/tmp
```

But when I check for existence from java:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
fs.exists(new Path("/tmp")); // returns true
fs.exists(new Path("/test")); // returns false
```

Same thing happens even when i created test inside /tmp. What's wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileSystem.get(conf)` may return the local file system where the `/tmp/` folder exists and `/test/` not exists. Try to specify the file system that you want to get:

```
FileSystem fs = new Path("hdfs://localhost:8020/").getFileSystem(conf);
```

I'm not sure about the port, you may need a 9000.